# Как раздавать WI-FI после авторизации по http

Tags: wifi, сервер, freeradius

Здравствуйте, допустим, есть задача раздавать wifi в кафе с такими условиями:

1. Клиент заходит в кафе и выбирает точку доступа.
2. Клиент заходит в браузер в надежде посидеть в интернете.
3. Его перенаправляет на страницу, через которую он должен авторизоваться, допустим, /auth-wifi.php, через что, не важно, хоть через соц. сеть, хоть просто нажмет на кнопку далее.
4. Если авторизовался, может пользоваться сколько угодно интернетом.

**Из того, что мне удалось нарыть:**

1. Компьютер с двумя сетевыми картами.
2. eth0 - интернет , eth1 - выход модем с wi-fi.
3. Установить [Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) сервер, я остановился пока на [PacketFence](http://www.packetfence.org/home.html), который будет пропускать через себя трафик и перенаправлять не авторизованных пользователей на /auth-wifi.php .
4. [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) для авторизации, допустим для хранения информации о пользователях в MySql.
5. Apache + PHP.

У кого какие мысли? В том ли я направлении?
Я пока не совсем понимаю нужность FreeRADIUS и для чего две сетевые карты.

Comment: У вас академический интерес сделать всё самому или надо решение чтобы работало?

Comment: На хабре неплохая статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/170949/.

Comment: > На хабре неплохая статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/170949/

Это для коропративных сетей. Для хотспота это вряд-ли подойдёт.